# Inequality query on two distinct date fields

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm developing an application with Google App Engine in Python.
In my application I should save the absences of students and their justifications, so I have a class:

```
class Absence(ndb.Model):
    day_begin = ndb.DateProperty(required=True)
    day_end = ndb.DateProperty(required=True)
    justified = ndb.BooleanProperty()
    date_range =  ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: generate_date_range(self.day_begin, self.day_end), repeated=True)
    student = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=SchoolUser, required=True)
```

For each day, a teacher could see all the absent students, so I must query for all absents with day_begin <= today <= day_end. As I can not do queries with multiple inequality filters, for now I save all the dates in the range in the field date_range, and then query on it.
I wanted to know if this approach is efficient and valid, or if there are better solutions? 
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a reasonable solution depending on the range you expect to see in the data and query filters. The App Engine FTS solution does something similar to support Numeric types. If you run into performance issues, you might be able to improve it by having multiple levels of granularity (for example days, months, years).

Geo Spacial queries run into the same problem. They solve it using space filling curves, see https://code.google.com/p/s2-geometry-library-java/.

Comment: You are right, I am going to store only the absences for one academic year, so they shouldn't be very numerous. Thank you!!!